# How to center a colorbar at a specific color for Seaborn Heatmap?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, heatmap

Is it possible to specify the color of center of colorbar in seaborn heatmap?
As example the ceneter of colorbar of the following heat map is 70, and I want to be specified with black color instead of white.
Thanks in advance.

[the example heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnrUb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DivergingNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.DivergingNorm.html#matplotlib-colors-divergingnorm) to specify an off-centered normalization. To create the cmap with black in the center, use [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-linear-segmented-colormaps)

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, DivergingNorm

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('BkR',['blue','black','red'])
norm = DivergingNorm(vmin=0, vcenter=70, vmax=100)

x,y = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(2,50))

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y,c=y, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]